# Linking individual queries in a unbound listbox in ACCESS 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007, listboxitems

I have created a unbound listbox. I have the box showing a list of queries I want the use to be able to select. My problem is I don't understand how to get the submit button to select the currently selected query and run it.

So how do I link the submit button to the listbox and have each item in the box submit its own query.

Comment: You example is a SELECT statement. You say you want to run it, but WHERE? You need some form of UI object to display it in. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I am trying to get this list box to execute each query that is generated from my SELECT statement.

Comment: Again, SELECT statements cannot be executed. Do you want to display the data returned by the SELECT statements?

Comment: What can I do with my current SELECT statement. right now I am populating this listbox with queries in the MSysObjects. How would I go about running each query from the populated listbox. if possible.

Comment: There is no way to tell the difference between a SELECT query and an "action" query, so you can't do much of anything other than DoCmd.OpenQuery, but that's not exactly something I'd put in a production application.

Comment: Well it is for an assignment, my teacher gave me an evil eye and told me it is out of the scope of the class so I guess i will stay with in the scope. thanks for the help. and Ben V answer did help me find another way to do it thanks everyone.

Comment: Your teacher seems to me, um, well, rather unqualified to be teaching Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the listbox contain a query name or the actual SQL?  Either way, something like

```
CurrentDB.Execute(Me![ListBox])
```

in the submit button event handler should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: The list box contains a query.

SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE [Type]=5 And Left([Name],1)<>"~" ORDER BY [Name];

Comment: CurrentDB.Execute does not work on anything but DDL or DML statements, i.e., no SELECT.

Comment: You're exactly right.  I assumed he wasn't doing a select since he wanted to execute it in the background.

Comment: I would have assumed the same thing. I don't think it's a very good UI, to be honest.